# Функция компилируется, но при запуске ошибка: "PLS-00221: is not a procedure or is undefined"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Написал простейшую функцию:

```
create or replace function test_func(test_in in number) return number is
    test_out number ;
BEGIN
    test_out:=test_in;
    RETURN test_out;
END;
```

Она компилируется. Но если пытаюсь её запустить:

```
BEGIN test_func(5); END;
```

то получаю следующую ошибку:

> PLS-00221: 'TEST_FUNC' is not a procedure or is undefined

Что не так с моей функцией?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle function compiles successfully but throws error while executing PLS-00221: is not a procedure or is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63637471) от участника [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/678855/david)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63637471

Answer (score 2):

С самой функцией всё в порядке.

Однако функция возвращает результат, и вызывать функцию можно только в том контексте, где этот результат может быть принят или присвоен. А именно: присвоение значения переменний, как актуальный параметр, в выражении, или в SQL запросе.

Вот несколько воспроизводимых примеров вызова функции:

```
declare
    ret int; 
begin
    ret := test_func (5);
    dbms_output.put_line ('ret='||ret);

    dbms_output.put_line ('test_func(6)='||test_func (6));

    if test_func (7) != 0 then  
        dbms_output.put_line ('result of test_func is non zero');
    end if;    
end;
/
ret=5
test_func(6)=6
result of test_func is non zero

select test_func (9) as result 
from dual 
where test_func (9) > 0
/

    RESULT
----------
         9
```